# Destroy all records that have the checked property equal to true

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using the following code to destroy records that have the checked property equal to true:

```
destroyRecords(model) {
  model.forEach((item) => {
    if (item.get('checked')) {
      item.destroyRecord();
    }
  });
}
```

Seems bad for performance check each one. Isn't there a better approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [invoke](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Enumerable.html#method_invoke) and [filterBy](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Enumerable.html#method_filterBy) to call `destroyRecord` on them all:

`model.filterBy('checked').invoke('destroyRecord');`